# Form elements array extract id

Tags: javascript, foreach

With JavaScript i retrieve an array of form elements.

```
[
    input#NOM.form-control.input-md, 
    input#SURNAME.form-control.input-md, 
    input#AGE.form-control.input-md, input#ADDRESS.form-control.input-md, 
    input#GENDER.form-control.input-md, input#COUNTRY.form-control.input-md
]
```

I'm trying to extract the id from it. I tried to use forEach without success. 
My code to get this data is the following :

```
const getAllFormElements = element =>
    Array.from(element.elements)
        .filter(tag => ["select", "textarea", "input"]
            .includes(tag.tagName.toLowerCase()));
const pageFormElements = getAllFormElements(document.getElementById("requestForm"));
console.log(pageFormElements);
```

Here is my form (very classical) :

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="requestForm">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-12 control-label" for="NOM">NOM</label>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input id="NOM" name="NOM" type="text" class="form-control input-md">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        ...
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-12 control-label" for="GENDER">GENDER</label>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input id="GENDER" name="GENDER" type="text" class="form-control input-md">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col" style="height: inherit">
            <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 30px">
                <div class="col-md-4 align-bottom">
                    <button id="btnOk" name="btnOk" class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

```js
const getAllFormElements = element =>
  Array.from(element.elements)
  .filter(tag => ["select", "textarea", "input"]
    .includes(tag.tagName.toLowerCase()));
const pageFormElements = getAllFormElements(document.getElementById("requestForm"));
console.log(pageFormElements);
```

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" id="requestForm">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-12 control-label" for="NOM">NOM</label>
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <input id="NOM" name="NOM" type="text" class="form-control input-md">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    ...
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-12 control-label" for="GENDER">GENDER</label>
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <input id="GENDER" name="GENDER" type="text" class="form-control input-md">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col" style="height: inherit">
      <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 30px">
        <div class="col-md-4 align-bottom">
          <button id="btnOk" name="btnOk" class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML of `#requestForm`?

Comment: I updated the post.

Comment: See snippet, it looks to work just fine. If it's not working, can you edit the snippet so that the problem is reproducible?

Comment: @davidvera, If you want to get the value of id attribute then try getting like this, ```pageFormElements.forEach(formEl => {
  console.log(formEl.getAttribute('id'));
})```

Comment: it works fine ! it's exactly what i expected. for a reason i don't understand i tried something close to this without success...